# Left Semi and Left Anti join at same time in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, join, pyspark

I have a table of ids say t1. And have another huge table say t2. I want to split t2 into two based on t1, such that one part contains all the ids present in t1 and another doesn't contain any ids present in t1.

One thing i can do is

```
cond = [col('t1.id') == col('t2.id')]
existsDF = t2.join(t1, cond, how="leftsemi")
absentDF = t2.join(t1, cond, how="left_anti")
```

But this uses two joins. Both t1 (~1M) and t2 (~1B) are really big

Is there a way to do this using only one join, or is this the most efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is good enough, but whith only one join, you can possibly persist your data after the join and benefit during the second actions you'll perform.

```py
t3 = t2.join(t1.select(col("t1.id")), on="id", how="left")

# fromp pyspark import StorageLevel
# t3.persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY)  # Use the appropriate StorageLevel

existsDF = t3.where(col("t1.id").isNotNull())
absentDF = t3.where(col("t1.id").isNull())
```

Comment: Thanks, i will try both methods to see what gives bette results. :)